# Create NSDate at specific time x days from now

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

I'm trying to learn Objective-C/iPhone SDK and right now I'm doing a kind of to-do app playing with local notifications.

I have a "**timeOfDay**" ivar stored as an NSDate from a DatePicker and a "**numberOfDays**" ivar stored as an NSNumber.

When I press a specific button, I would like to schedule a local notification x **numberOfDays** from the time the button is pressed but at the specific **timeOfDay**.

I seems easy to add an NSTimeInterval to the current date which would give me the a way to schedule the notification **numberOfDays** from current time but adding the timeOfDay feature makes it more complex.

What would be the correct way of achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `NSDateComponents` to add time intervals to an existing date while respecting all the quirks of the user's current calendar.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

// Get the year, month and day of the current date
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit| NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

// Extract the hour, minute and second components from self.timeOfDay
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:self.timeOfDay];

// Apply the time components to the components of the current day
dateComponents.hour = timeComponents.hour;
dateComponents.minute = timeComponents.minute;
dateComponents.second = timeComponents.second;

// Create a new date with both components merged
NSDate *currentDateWithTimeOfDay = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

// Create new components to add to the merged date
NSDateComponents *futureComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
futureComponents.day = [self.numberOfDays integerValue];
NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:futureComponents toDate:currentDateWithTimeOfDay options:0];
```

Comment: does this assume that self.timeOfDay includes the current date (so that adding numberOfDays days to that date gives you correct time in the future)?

Comment: the line just before newDate should be futureComponents and there's a  "]" too much in line 4 but other than that it works perfectly.

A very fast and very useful answer indeed Mark Adams. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

There is a pretty simple method to do this that won't involve as many lines of code.

```
int numDays = 5;
myDate = [myDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*numDays];
```

Comment: Allthough this is usefull, it doesn't respect winter/summer time.

Comment: I agree. Since writing this, I've learned there are better ways. It works in a quick pinch, but can not be counted on for date precision.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (id)dateWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds sinceDate:(NSDate *)date
```

That should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: This approach will fall apart during events like daylight savings time and leap years.

Comment: Not exactly, as this will not take daylight savings into account. If you want to do it the right way, use `NSDateComponents`, see http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: How does that solve my problem with getting the correct time of day? I can't just add the hours and minutes of the "timeOfDay" date and add them as the button can be pressed at any time.

Thanks :)